# Python: calculate value for each pair of values in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary consisting of key:[list] in which the list is a fixed and even number of binary values, ie:

```
{'a':[0,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,1,1,0,0,0]}
```

For each key, I need to return a new value for each *pair* of values in the original dict, such that for pair(1,1) = 3, pair(0,1) = 2, pair(1,0) = 1, pair(0,0) = 0.

For the example above, output would be:

```
{'a':[2,1,2],'b':[3,1,0]}
```

New to both python and programming in general, and haven't found what I'm looking for on SO.  Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attack just the pairing part:

```
def paired(binlist, map={(1, 1): 3, (0, 1): 2, (1, 0): 1, (0, 0): 0}):
    return [map[tuple(binlist[i:i + 2])] for i in range(0, len(binlist), 2)]
```

Then apply this to your dictionary:

```
{k: paired(v) for k, v in input_dictionary.iteritems()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> paired([0,1,1,0,0,1])
[2, 1, 2]
>>> paired([1,1,1,0,0,0])
[3, 1, 0]
>>> input_dictionary = {'a':[0,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,1,1,0,0,0]}
>>> {k: paired(v) for k, v in input_dictionary.iteritems()}
{'a': [2, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small snippet I could come up with was :

```
>>> testDict = {'a':[0,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,1,1,0,0,0]}
>>> referenceDict = {(0, 1):2, (0, 0):0, (1, 0):1, (1, 1):3}
>>> for key, value in testDict.items():
        finalList = [referenceDict[elem] for elem in zip(value[::2], value[1::2])]
        testDict[key] = finalList       
>>> testDict
{'a': [2, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 1, 0]}
```

`value[::2]` is [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).

Packing this up into a function for use :

```
def testFunction(inputDict):
    referenceDict = {(0, 1):2, (0, 0):0, (1, 0):1, (1, 1):3}
    for key, value in inputDict.items():
        finalList = [referenceDict[elem] for elem in zip(value[::2], value[1::2])]
        inputDict[key] = finalList
    return inputDict
```

Example -

```
>>> testFunction({'a':[0,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,1,1,0,0,0]})
{'a': [2, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> D = {'a': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],'b': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
>>> {k: [v[i] + 2 * v[i+1] for i in range(0, len(v), 2)] for k, v in D.items()}
{'a': [2, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 1, 0]}
```